# How to reset RadAsyncUpload after submission in the code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radupload

I wonder how to reset (clear) [RadAsyncUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)  and leave the component as in the initial state

after the submission in the code behind?

---

## my aspx ::

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="rada_attach" OnClientFileUploaded="onClientFileUploaded"
MultipleFileSelection="Disabled" InitialFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileInputsCount="1"
Width="100%" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add code below to Click event handler of submit button (not tested)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "clearUpload", String.Format("$find('{0}').deleteAllFileInputs()", rada_attach.ClientID), true);
```

Comment: `$find()` will return null in this case, as the control might not be ready on that state. Even `jQuery's $(document).ready()` will not help. Official support recommends to use a small timeout  like `setTimeout(function () { $find('" + control.ClientID + "').deleteAllFileInputs(); }, 100);` to make sure, `$find()` will find the desired object. [Source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/find-doesn-t-work-when-called-through-scriptmanager-registerstartupscript)

Answer (score 2):

You want to clear the list of items after Upload?
if yes,according to this [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/radasyncupload-clear-uploaded-files.aspx) you can do like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function clientFileUploaded(sender, args) {
       var count = sender._getRowCount();

       if (count > 2) {
           Array.removeAt(sender._uploadedFiles, 0);
           sender.deleteFileInputAt(0);
           sender.updateClientState();
       }
   }
```